# Vertically Align Text within Bootstrap Button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I could use a hand vertically aligning text within a Bootstrap button.

If I use the  class the text is vertically aligned like I want, but if I use the   class the text is top-aligned and nothing I do seems to change it. Any ideas?

Screenshot of the buttons:

[image: Screenshot of the buttons]

```css
/* added by editor for demo purpose */
button {
  min-height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-1 py-1 vh-100 align-middle">
  <a href="#link" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-50 align-middle" type="submit">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
    <p>This is text.</p>
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-50 align-middle" type="submit">
    <h1>Header 2</h1>
    <p>This is more text.</p>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that an `<a>`nchor remains an inline-element in Bootstrap. As such it has a line-height to which it centers. You can solve this with flexbox by adding `d-flex flex-column justify-content-center`

```css
/* added by editor for demo purpose */
button {
  min-height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-1 py-1 vh-100 align-middle">
  <a href="#link" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-50 align-middle" type="submit">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
    <p>This is text.</p>
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg w-50 align-middle" type="submit">
    <h1>Header 2</h1>
    <p>This is more text.</p>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you @tacoshy! This completely fixed it. I had tried adding "d-flex" on the <a> tag and on a parent div but the "flex-column" and "justify-content-center" were what I was missing. Not very intuitive but I'll remember it now!